# Django AttributeError object has no attribute 'upper'

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I am implementing an API for an image labelling app.
I have customised a create() method for Tagging. A Tagging contains a tag, which is an object containing a name and a language. To make tags easier to compare to each other, I have to save all tags either in upper or lower case.

**serializers.py**

```
  def create(self, validated_data):
    """Create and return a new tagging"""

    user = None
    request = self.context.get("request")
    if request and hasattr(request, "user"):
      user = request.user

    score = 0

    tag_data = validated_data.pop('tag', None)
    if tag_data:
      tag = Tag.objects.get_or_create(**tag_data)[0]
      validated_data['tag'] = tag

    tagging = Tagging(
      user=user,
      gameround=validated_data.get("gameround"),
      resource=validated_data.get("resource"),
      tag=validated_data.get("tag"),
      created=datetime.now(),
      score=score,
      origin=""
    )
    tagging.save()
    return tagging
```

I have tried both this

```
tag=validated_data.get("tag").upper()
```

and this:

```
tag=validated_data.get("tag").lower()
```

and I get an AttributeError 'Tag' object has no attribute 'upper' or 'Tag' object has no attribute 'lower'.

I want for this tag in the tagging object:

```
{
        "gameround_id": 65,
        "resource_id": 11601,
        "tag": {
            "name": "TagToTestNow",
            "language": "de"
        }
}
```

to be saved something like "TAGTOTESTNOW" or "tagtotestnow" to make Tag comparison easier.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: you have already poped the tag, ```tag_data = validated_data.pop('tag', None)```,  when you do ```validated_data.get('pop')``` it returns ```None```.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you already created the tag, so it's not a dict anymore. You can do `tag=tag` directly in you `Tagging` object creation.

If you want all your tags to have the same case, you have to slightly modify the way you create your Tag in the first place, as follow:

```py
tag = Tag.objects.get_or_create(
    language=tag_data['language'],
    name=tag_data['name'].upper()
)[0]
```

Comment: Thank  you so much! This worked.